# WHMCS Action Hooks Not Firing

Tags: php, hook, whmcs

I have been pounding my head against the desk for a week now and have finally decided it's time to ask for help.

I am trying to create action hooks for WHMCS for when a client performs a certain action. For example, i'm just trying to get it to return the variables it grabs. Essentially all I need is the USER ID, but for testing purposes I asked it to return several variables.

Below is an example of my code:

```
/*
 * Define Hook Functions 
*/
function hook_changedpassword($vars) {
    $userid = $vars['userid'];
    $firstname = $vars['firstname'];
    $lastname = $vars['lastname'];
    $email = $vars['email'];
    $password = $vars['password'];

    return print_r($vars);
}

function hook_clientmerged($vars) {
    $userid = $vars['userid'];
    $firstname = $vars['firstname'];
    $lastname = $vars['lastname'];
    $email = $vars['email'];
    $password = $vars['password'];

    return print_r($vars);  
}

function hook_clientupdated($vars) {
    $userid = $vars['userid'];
    $firstname = $vars['firstname'];
    $lastname = $vars['lastname'];
    $email = $vars['email'];
    $password = $vars['password'];

    return print_r($vars);  
}

function hook_emailverification($vars) {
    $userid = $vars['userid'];
    $firstname = $vars['firstname'];
    $lastname = $vars['lastname'];
    $email = $vars['email'];
    $password = $vars['password'];

    return print_r($vars);  
}

/*
 * Start Add Hook Functions 
*/

// when client changes portal password
add_hook('ClientChangePassword', 1, "hook_changedpassword");

// when client accounts are merged.
add_hook('AfterClientMerge', 1, "hook_clientmerged");

// when client updates client details
add_hook('AfterClientMerge', 1, "hook_clientupdated");

// when client verifies email address
add_hook('ClientEmailVerificationComplete', 1, "hook_emailverification");
```

It's not associated with any module or addon, and I don't know if that's the problem, but the Hooks Wiki makes it appear that regardless, these will be processed when these actions are taken.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you place this code? if not using a module, then place it at: whmcs_path/includes/hooks/my_custom_hooks.php

Comment: I did. The file is located inside the includes directory, inside the hooks folder, in a file called alert_hooks.php

And it still doesn't fire the hooks upon the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [Hook documentatio](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks/hook-index/)n, some hooks doesn't support returning any values, for example, [AfterClientMerge](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/client/#afterclientmerge), No response supported.

Probably your hooks are firing, but they're doing nothing. WHMCS somehow suppressing browser output in some hooks, even echo will not show an output.

Such hooks expected to perform an action, like updating DB table or sending an email, etc.

For debugging, use the following statement to output variables to a file instead outputting them to the browser:

```
error_log(print_r($vars, true), 3, __DIR__.'/file.log');
```

Function becomes:

```
function hook_clientmerged($vars) {
    $userid = $vars['userid'];
    $firstname = $vars['firstname'];
    $lastname = $vars['lastname'];
    $email = $vars['email'];
    $password = $vars['password'];

    error_log(print_r($vars, true), 3, __DIR__.'/file.log');  
}
```

**Edit: To insert data to database**

File: example_hook.php

```
<?php
use WHMCS\Database\Capsule as DB;

function hook_clientmerged($vars) {
    $userid = $vars['userid'];
    $firstname = $vars['firstname'];
    $lastname = $vars['lastname'];
    $email = $vars['email'];
    $password = $vars['password'];

    //Insert vars in the database
    DB::table('table_name')->insert(
        ['field1' => $userid, 'field2' => $firstname]
    ); 
}
```

Comment: The error_log command isn't doing anything. I have debug enabled. I'm not looking to return anything in particular. I'm more looking to just return $vars, and insert it into a database for an alert notification.

Comment: you can change where error_log adds messages, if the hook triggered, you should find a file with name file.log in the hooks folder.

Comment: Also added an example on how to insert data to database

Comment: To add onto a small point about WHMCS suppressing output, it's completely true and rather annoying sometimes for development environments. WHMCS will typically only allow outputs into fields on a web page such as an error dialogue box.

Comment: Added your DB insert code...doesn't insert.
`code
function hook_changedpassword($vars) {
  //Insert vars in the database
    DB::table('tblclientnotifications')->insert(
        [
        'id' => null,
        'recip' => 1,
        'title' => "Password Changed",
        'description' => "Your password has changed.",
        'unread' => 1
        ]
    ); 
}

// when client changes portal password
add_hook('ClientChangePassword', 1, "hook_changedpassword");
/code`
Above is the changed code.

Comment: Well, that's so strange! Enable Error Display in WHMCS settings, may be you get a warning/error that might help.

Comment: I was using an older version of WHMCS. Now that I've updated it is working. Not sure why, but it took my forever to find this post to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So there are three stages you need to track to debug this:

1) Are the hooks being loaded? You can check this by enabling hook debugging:

https://docs.whmcs.com/Other_Tab#Hooks_Debug_Mode

2) Are the hooks firing? Once you enable hook debugging you can perform an action and make sure the hook point you attached to is firing by reviewing the activity log.

3) Is your hook code executing? Once you know the hook point is being trigger you want to show that your code is executing. My preferred way to do this simply is the logActivity() function:

https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/logging/

A simple way to check what variables are present when the hook is triggered is:

```
logActivity('Hook variables: '.print_r($vars, true));
```